# Не видит файл .js из html

Tags: javascript, html

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>JS Music Player</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Music Player</h1>

<div class="music-container play" id="music-container">
 <div class="music-info">
  <h4 id="title">ukulele</h4>
  <div class="progress-container" id="progress-container">
    <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <audio src="music/nazare.mp3" id="audio"></audio>

 <div class="img-container">
   <img src="img/nazare.jpg" alt="music-cover" id="cover"/>
 </div>

 <div class="navigation">
  <button id="prev" class="action-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-backward"></i>
  </button>
  <button id="play" class="action-btn action-btn-big">
    <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
  </button>
  <button id="next" class="action-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-forward"></i>
  </button>
</div>
</div>
<script>src="app.js"
  console.log('1stranica')
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

console.log() уже не видит...

```
console.log('hurma!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')

const musicContainer = document.getElementById('music-container')

const playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');

const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
const progressContainer = document.getElementById('progress-container');
const title = document.getElementById('title');
const cover = document.getElementById('cover');

//Song Titles
const songs = ['gospel','search','nazare'];

// Keep track of song
let songIndex = 1;

//Load song details into DOM
loadSong(songs[songIndex]);

//Update song details
function loadSong(song){
    title.innerText = song;
    audio.src = `music/${song}.mp3`;
    cover.src = `img/${song}.jpg`;
 }
```

Comment: `<script>src="app.js"` - where did you see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не

```
<script>src="app.js"
  console.log('1stranica')
</script>
```

a

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: console.log() я добавил чтобы видеть выполняется ли код внутри.

Comment: OMG мою внимательность.... Спасибо мил человек!